# SensorEventListener doesn't get unregistered with unregisterListener() method

Tags: java, android, listener, sensors

I have very simple Android app: in activity I have a button and I start/stop the OrientationListener. However, after unregistering it, in ddms I can still see the thread *android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread] (Running)*.

The registration code:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
if (sensors.size() > 0)
{
    sensor = sensors.get(0);
    running = sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

and unregistration:

```
try
{
    if (sensorManager != null && sensorEventListener != null)
    {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener,sensor);
        running = false;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

The `unregisterListener()` method does get executed, however it doesn't kill the sensors thread very often, which keeps running and draining the battery. After few hours my app is listed with 20-30% battery drain. How is that possible? How can I make sure, that the sensor gets unregistered? I don't get any exceptions nor any errors in the logcat. I tried running the listener in the Service - same thing.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I solved it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504474/android-thread-cannot-unregister-sensoreventlistener


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504474/android-thread-cannot-unregister-sensoreventlistener

Answer (score 5):

In my case, to solve this problem I needed to correct the context I was using to get SensorManager. I was inside a Service, and I needed to get the SensorManager this way:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

So, just certify if you are getting the SensorManager the correct way.

Comment: Solid advice here! This was 1 of 3 issues of mine. Ref other comments I've made in this post.

Comment: My problem too, `applicationContext.getSystemService()` and `Service.getSystemService()` returned two different `SensorManager`s and made it not working! THANKS! But my question then: which one should be used within a service ?

Comment: Man, I spent 2 hours on this. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You don't show enough code to tell for sure, but perhaps your test

```
if (sensorManager != null && sensorEventListener != null)
```

simply is not accurate. That is, `sensorManager` or `sensorEventListener` may be `null` when you are still registered as listening.

Comment: Good point here. This threw me off- especially when registering sensors in a background thread (without proper context).

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the manager to null

```
sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener,sensor);
sensorManager = null;
```

and then obtain the manager again when you need it. This should make the thread finish consistently (it did in my case). I haven't found any documentation explaining this behavior but would be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: Following this advise (and others in this SO post) did the trick for me. This was part of the overall issue. I also: 1) I also implemented proper boolean checks in places like registration, unregistration and onSensorChanged(). 2) Kept proper Context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem. I checked the Android code.
The relevant code is in SensorManager.java

```
private void unregisterListener(Object listener) {
    if (listener == null) {
        return;
    }

    synchronized (sListeners) {
        final int size = sListeners.size();
        for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++) {
            ListenerDelegate l = sListeners.get(i);
            if (l.getListener() == listener) {
                sListeners.remove(i);
                // disable all sensors for this listener
                for (Sensor sensor : l.getSensors()) {
                    disableSensorLocked(sensor);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
        public void run() {
            //Log.d(TAG, "entering main sensor thread");
            final float[] values = new float[3];
            final int[] status = new int[1];
            final long timestamp[] = new long[1];
            Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);

            if (!open()) {
                return;
            }

            synchronized (this) {
                // we've open the driver, we're ready to open the sensors
                mSensorsReady = true;
                this.notify();
            }

            while (true) {
                // wait for an event
                final int sensor = sensors_data_poll(sQueue, values, status, timestamp);

                int accuracy = status[0];
                synchronized (sListeners) {
                    if (sensor == -1 || sListeners.isEmpty()) {
                        // we lost the connection to the event stream. this happens
                        // when the last listener is removed or if there is an error
                        if (sensor == -1 && !sListeners.isEmpty()) {
                            // log a warning in case of abnormal termination
                            Log.e(TAG, "_sensors_data_poll() failed, we bail out: sensors=" + sensor);
                        }
                        // we have no more listeners or polling failed, terminate the thread
                        sensors_destroy_queue(sQueue);
                        sQueue = 0;
                        mThread = null;
                        break;
                    }
                    final Sensor sensorObject = sHandleToSensor.get(sensor);
                    if (sensorObject != null) {
                        // report the sensor event to all listeners that
                        // care about it.
                        final int size = sListeners.size();
                        for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++) {
                            ListenerDelegate listener = sListeners.get(i);
                            if (listener.hasSensor(sensorObject)) {
                                // this is asynchronous (okay to call
                                // with sListeners lock held).
                                listener.onSensorChangedLocked(sensorObject,
                                        values, timestamp, accuracy);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, "exiting main sensor thread");
        }
    }
}
```

So it looks like the thread should be terminated when there are no listeners any more

Comment: I am also having the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504474/android-thread-cannot-unregister-sensoreventlistener

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue.

Workaround to stop the sensor.

I used a static boolean `mIsSensorUpdateEnabled`. Set it to 'false' when you want to stop getting values from sensors. 
And in onSensorChanged() method, check the value of the boolean variable and again make to call to unregister the sensors. And this time, it works. The sensors would be unregistered and you will no longer get onSensorChanged callback.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private static boolean mIsSensorUpdateEnabled = false;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;

    @override
    protected void onCreate(){
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }

    private startSensors(){
        mAccelerometer =  mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        int delay = 100000; //in microseconds equivalent to 0.1 sec
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mAccelerometer,
                delay
        );
        mIsSensorUpdateEnabled =true;
    }

    private stopSensors(){
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
        mIsSensorUpdateEnabled =false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (!mIsSensorUpdateEnabled) {
            stopSensors();
            Log.e("SensorMM", "SensorUpdate disabled. returning");
            return;
        }
        //Do other work with sensor data
    }
}
```

Comment: This was key to resolving my issue. Reference my other comments in this SO post.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a problem with scope.  Try logging the values of sensorEventListener and sensor when you register and unregister them. (.toString())  to make sure that they are the same.

Comment: That's not it. They are exactly the same.

Comment: This was key advice. Adding good DEBUG helped me chase down several issues, 2 big issues being: 1) Proper registration/unregister (within Context), 2) Implement proper boolean checks in places like registration, unregistration and onSensorChanged(). 3) I implemented registration in a background thread (beware!).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declaration of SensorManager
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener;
```

onCreate call To

```
try {
         sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener=new SensorEventListener() {
            int orientation = -1;

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                if (event.values[1] < 6.5 && event.values[1] > -6.5) {
                    if (orientation != 1) {
                        Log.d("Sensor", "Landscape");
                    }
                    orientation = 1;
                } else {
                    if (orientation != 0) {
                        Log.d("Sensor", "Portrait");


                    }
                    orientation = 0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        },
                mAccelerometer=sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please call to on Destroy

```
if (sensorManager != null && mAccelerometer != null) 
{ 
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener, mAccelerometer); sensorManager = null; 
}
```

Comment: please check to above anser

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue